# How to replace CR+LF with <br />?

Tags: coldfusion, textarea, newline

For example:

A user submits a form with a `<textarea name="mytext" cols="35" rows="2"></textarea>` and presses <kbd>ENTER</kbd> within it. How would I replace the CR-LF with a `<br />`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

CF has a function for this called ParagraphFormat():

```
<cfset form.userText = paragraphFormat(form.usertext)/>
```

From the help docs -

Replaces characters in a string:

- Single newline characters (CR/LF sequences) with spaces
- Double newline characters with HTML paragraph tags (`<p>`)

It may do *more* than you want in that it also looks for double line breaks and adds `<p>` and `</p>` tags.

Ben also has an enhanced version (a UDF) called paragraph2 that would be easy to modify to get the exact affect you want. Here's the link:

http://www.cflib.org/udf/ParagraphFormat2

Comment: I think ParagraphFormat2 may be better in this case as it does turn single line breaks into "<br />" (as well as double line breaks into HTML paragraphs).

Answer (score 15):

`<cfset localVars.ReturnString = REReplace(localVars.ReturnString, "\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r", "<br />", "all")>`

You shouldn't hit `\n\r` naturally, but it can happen if it's being inserted by a dev who has forgotten the correct order.

That's a subset of a more generalised function to replace end of lines (EOL) chars with something else based on what you're doing (e.g. having to write out in Windows/Linux format, .ics files, html, cfheaders, etc)

```
<cffunction name="ReplaceEOL" access="public" output="false" returntype="string" hint="Replaces EOL codes with other characters">
    <cfargument name="String" required="true" type="string">
    <cfargument name="ReplaceWith" required="true" type="string">

    <cfreturn REReplace(Arguments.String, "\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r", Arguments.ReplaceWith, "all")>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: I just fixed your first example and simplified the code, but realised this wouldn't actually work as intended - the individual `\r` and `\n` get matched before the combined versions (earliest match wins in most modern regex), so needed to move them to the end of the alternation - .e. `\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r` - I went ahead and fixed that as well, but just wanted to point it out since it's useful to keep in mind.

Comment: Although personally I always just remove all carriage returns and then only have to deal with newlines, e.g. `String.replaceAll('\r','').replaceAll('\n','<br/>')`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of replacing it with br I would use the [ParagraphFormat](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_09.html) function when displaying the values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the paragraphFormat() function but sometimes a replace function helps you visualize what is actually happening.

An example: `<cfset TheText=replace("#form.myText#",chr(13)&chr(10),"<br />","all")>`

This replaces all carriage return-line feeds with an html line break

Answer (score 0):

I actually prefer something like this:

```
<p>#REReplace(theParagraphText, "[#chr(10)#]+", "</p><p>", "ALL")#</p>
```

As it combines multiple line breaks into a single paragraph break.

Comment: `[#chr(10)#]+` is a long-winded way to write `\n+` - but regardless of that, since it doesn't handle carriage returns, this is inferior to the [existing answer given by nosilleg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330993/how-to-replace-crlf-with-br#11331321).