# message is not displayed on a new line

Tags: javascript, html, css, coldfusion

I am trying to display the message when I make a comment and it is not displaying all the new lines.

so I have a text area

```
<textarea style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px; border: 1px solid ##dddddd; padding: 2px;"></textarea>
```

and when I make a comment with it , its shows the way its supposed to

```
text 1 
text 2
```

this is the output of the message

```
<div style="padding-top: 2px; padding-left: 10px; height:50px;">
    <font class="text_medium">
    <font color="##555555">
        #message#
    </font>
    </font>
</div>
```

but when I approve the comment the text shows

```
text 1 text 2
```

how do I make my #message# show these new lines that were showing from text area ? thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not clear. How do you approve the comments, does it involve any server side scripting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace CR+LF with <br />?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330993/how-to-replace-crlf-with-br)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're passing as plain text. There are a few things you can do

```
<pre>#message#</pre>
```

Or you can use a regex to replace

```
#REReplace(Message, "\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r", "<br />", "all")#
```

**source:** [How to replace CR+LF with <br />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330993/how-to-replace-crlf-with-br)

Comment: thanks!...for some reason this worked the best for me

Comment: @Manual As Mark said, you're probably losing a piece of your carriage return somewhere, which is what this replace catches effectively.

Answer (score 2):

To give you a ColdFusion specific answer (rather than just CSS) try this:

```
<div style="padding-top: 2px; padding-left: 10px; height:50px;">
    <font class="text_medium">
    <font color="##555555">
        #paragraphformat(message)#
    </font>
    </font>
</div>
```

That automatically replaces carraige returns with BR tags.

-mark

Comment: thanks...for some reason it doesn't work for me..it's probably some conflict that I have in the code.

Comment: Hmmm.. is something scrubbing out the carraige return/lb?  They should be chr(10) and chr(13).  That's what this tag would look for.

Comment: you are probably right !...I'm gonna have to look through what's wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pre` tag

```
<div class="text_medium">
    <pre style="color:#555555">
        #message#
    </pre>
</div>
```

Also suggesting you don't use `font` as `font` is **HTML5 Deprecated Tag**