# Why is my JSON invalid even though it looks correct?

Tags: javascript, json, coldfusion, lucee

I've been working on this for quite a while, and I just don't understand why my JSON is invalid...

JSONLint is showing this error

```
    Error: Parse error on line 107:
...pair?",      "answer": "Yes, as long as the
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

This is the fragment of the JSON

```
{
    "tags": "already transferred",
    "question": "Can we transfer customers who have already been transferred previously? what is the dispo? warm transfer or already contacted?",
    "answer": "Yes, mark as already contacted."
},

{
    "tags": "secured debt",
    "question": "If customer only has secured debts, can we still offer credit repair?",
    "answer": "Yes, as long as they have at least $100 in secured/unsecured debt.
    "},




    {
        "tags": "state",
        "question": "Is the program state sensitive?",
        "answer": "Yes, each partner has particular states that they service. The script engine will only offer services when the state is valid for partner who has that service."
    },
```

It's failing where it says 'Yes, as long'

JSON is created in ColdFusion dynamically.

```
<cfscript>faqCounter=1;</cfscript>
    <CFLOOP query="getFAQs">
         <cfoutput>
            {"tags":"#getFAQs.tags#","question":"#getFAQs.question#","answer":"#getFAQs.answer#"}<cfif faqCounter<getFAQCount.getFAQPertinentCount>,</cfif>
         </cfoutput>
        <cfscript>faqCounter++;</cfscript>
    </CFLOOP>
```

Comment: Is that an array? Because right now it's just three objects.

Comment: You can't have a literal newline in a JSON string, it should be the escape sequence `\n`.

Comment: It's an array of objects, of which I just included a fragment.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `},{` after the line `"answer": "Yes, mark as already contacted."`?

Comment: Hi Barmar, can you please show where the literal newline is? For all the other objects within that array, there are no errors. Only that one is giving an error.

Comment: There's a line break after the word `debt.`, the closing quote is on the next line.

Comment: @olegA the \n newline is right before the closing quote here: secured/unsecured debt."

Comment: The odd thing is I have like 10-12 of such arrays in the data package, all of them have these line breaks in the output, but they all work with the exception of this..

Comment: Don't try to create JSON by filling in each property separately. Use the `SerializeJSON()` function on the entire array.

Comment: Your code will also fail if any of the variables has double quotes in them, since they won't be escaped.

Comment: Let me try to add this to the database after the 'debt.' Is there anything particular that's causing it?

Comment: Don't try to patch it in the database. Your whole approach is wrong. Do what I said above.

Comment: What version of CF are you using? There are simpler options in CF2016+

Comment: It is Lucee that I'm using

Comment: Hi Ageax, do you know how to get read of the the carriage return? I tried to use serializeJSON, but it didn't seem to do it.

Comment: @OlegA - [Lucee 5.2.8.39](https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-974) added support for changing how queries are serialized, in your Application.cfc settings. So you don't have to build your own array of structures anymore. SerializeJSON() will do it automatically, i.e. `<cfset json = serializeJSON(yourQuery)>`.

Comment: @OlegA - SerializeJSON() won't remove the carriage returns - only escape them so they don't break your JSON. If you only need to remove them for this task, after converting to a JSON string, just run a replace on the generated JSON string: `replace(text, "\n", "", "all)`. If you're trying to remove them permanently, you'll have to update the code that inserts the values into your database AND update any existing records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

( *As the other answers already pointed out, the problem is the un-escaped new line, which breaks the JSON. That's one of the reasons to avoid DIY JSON. Instead, use the built in function [SerializeJSON()](https://cfdocs.org/serializejson).* )

**Lucee 5.2.8.39+**

Try the new support for [JSON serialization-related settings in the Application.cfc](https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-974). The new settings let you override the bizarre default CF has for serializing query objects:

```
// serialize queries as an array of structures AND
// preserves the column name case used in the sql
this.serialization.preserveCaseForStructKey = true;
this.serialization.serializeQueryAs = "struct";
```

Now you can skip all the query looping. Simply execute the query and call `serializeJSON( yourQuery )`, to generate a wonderfully sane looking string like this:

```
[
  {
    "answer": "Yes, mark as already contacted.",
    "tags": "already transferred",
    "question": "Can we transfer customers who have already been transferred previously? what is the dispo? warm transfer or already contacted?"
  },
  {
    "answer": "Yes, as long as they have at least $100 in secured/unsecured debt.  ",
    "tags": "secured debt",
    "question": "If customer only has secured debts, can we still offer credit repair?"
  }
]
```

**Earlier Lucee versions**

For earlier versions, do what [@Barmar recommended](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57877341/why-is-my-json-invalid-even-though-it-looks-correct#comment102179602_57877341). Build an array of structures. Then use [serializeJSON](https://cfdocs.org/serializejson) to convert the array into a properly formatted JSON string.

[Runnable Example](https://trycf.com/gist/ac76977333095bf4c349432d7b7bad9a/acf2016?theme=monokai)

```
   <cfset yourArray = []>

   <cfloop query="getFAQs">
      <cfset yourArray.append( { "tags" : getFAQs.tags
                               , "question" : getFAQs.question
                               , "answer": getFAQs.answer
                             } )>    
   </cfloop>

   <cfset jsonString = serializeJSON( yourArray )>
```

**How to remove the new line?**

After generating a "proper" JSON string, run a [replace()](https://cfdocs.org/replace) and substitute `\n` with an empty string.

```
  <cfset jsonString  = replace(jsonString , "\n", "", "all")>
```

To permanently remove them, you'll have to find the code inserting them into the database in the first place, and modify it there. Also, update any existing database records to remove the "\n".

Answer (score 4):

you have a CRLF inside the the quotes ""

```
"answer": "Yes, as long as they have at least $100 in secured/unsecured debt.
"},
```

[image]

Comment: Do you how to get rid of it? I was trying to serializeJSON it but it still is showing me that  string as a problem? It's just one object in the entire array, when I delete it, everything works.

Comment: @OlegA The solution seems to be to use paragraphFormat to remove CRLFs in your character string: paragraphFormat(getFAQs.answer). This answer can help you with your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330993/how-to-replace-crlf-with-br

Comment: @pedrozopayares - Good thought, but that's not the right function. It's designed for displaying output on screen. In some cases it'll convert them to an html `<p>`, which is probably undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the string contains a newline as a literal, which should be `\n`.  In most languages you are able to filter or serialize data into JSON and it will handle these conversions for you.

Consider the following code snippets from https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/serializejson.html

this script utilizing the `serializeJSON()` function converts data into JSON

```
<cfscript>
       example = structnew();
       example.firstname = "Yes";
       example.lastname = "Man";
       // changing the default serialization by specifying the type of "firstname" as string
       metadata = {firstname: {type:"string"}};
       example.setMetadata(metadata);
       writeoutput(SerializeJSON(example));
</cfscript>
```

```
{"LASTNAME":"Man","FIRSTNAME":"Yes"}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24015714)

Comment: @AlFoиceѫ thanks for the suggestion, I originally intended to add this answer as a comment, but apparently I do not have enough reputation to comment on other people's questions, will edit my response.